# While creating Drawer layout in android issue of 'mToolbar' symbol is not resolve

Tags: android

```
   mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,          /* DrawerLayout object */
            mToolbar,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
```

While creating drawer in android I'm facing the issue of Symbol not resolve,

Comment: What do you mean by Symbol not resolve? Is there an exception? Can you post the exception?

Comment: mToolbar is in red, When we hoer on mToolbar the tool_tip come Symbol can not resolve

Comment: This means your mDrawerToggle is not defined. Do you have `private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;` defined in your Activity?